# How to execute php file on calls to CSV?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to find out how to generate CSV file with php on nginx when CSV called for download. E.g. when facebook calls [www.site.com/feeds/feed1.csv](http://www.site.com/feeds/feed1.csv) server should execute [www.site.com/feeds/feed1.php](http://www.site.com/feeds/feed1.php) and generate feed1.csv. I'm failing to define server rule to redirect.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. The simplest is probably `rewrite ^(/feeds/.*)\.csv$ $1.php last;`

Comment: Thanks so much, will try!